# Table to fit beamer slide

Tags: tables, beamer

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor,hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usetheme{boxes}
\usecolortheme{default}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\beamersetaveragebackground{white}
\pretocmd{\tableofcontents}{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}}{}{}
\apptocmd{\tableofcontents}{\end{minipage}}{}{}
  \usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{table}[]
            \centering
            \caption{My caption}
            \label{my-label}
            \resizebox{11.5cm}{!}{
            \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
                \hline
                Kraj                   & Okres zwiększonej podaży pieniądza & Liczba kwartałów      & Liczba epizodów       & Inflacja                   \\ \hline
                Kanada                 & 1972 Q1 - 1974 Q2                  & 4                     & 5                     & {\color[HTML]{009901} TAK} \\ \hline
                & 1978 Q4 - 1983 Q1                  & 18                    &                       & {\color[HTML]{FE0000} NIE} \\ \hline
                & 1986 Q4 - 1987 Q3                  & 4                     &                       & {\color[HTML]{FE0000} NIE} \\ \hline
                & 1990 Q3 - 1993 Q4                  & 14                    &                       & {\color[HTML]{FE0000} NIE} \\ \hline
                & 1996 Q1 - 1998 Q4                  & 12                    &                       & {\color[HTML]{009901} TAK} \\ \hline
                \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}              & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}      \\ \hline
                Dania                  & 1975 Q4 - 1978 Q1                  & 10                    & 4                     & {\color[HTML]{009901} TAK} \\ \hline
                & 1984 Q2 - 1988 Q4                  & 19                    &                       & {\color[HTML]{FE0000} NIE} \\ \hline
                & 1992 Q2 - 1994 Q3                  & 10                    &                       & {\color[HTML]{009901} TAK} \\ \hline
                & 1996 Q4 - 1999 Q3                  & 12                    &                       & {\color[HTML]{009901} TAK} \\ \hline
                \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}              & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}      \\ \hline
                Francja                & 1990 Q3 - 1993 Q4                  & 14                    & 2                     & {\color[HTML]{FE0000} NIE} \\ \hline
                & 1995 Q3 - 1996 Q3                  & 4                     &                       & {\color[HTML]{FE0000} NIE} \\ \hline
            \end{tabular}}
        \end{table}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

It generates a table that it tilted to the right of a beamer slide i want this table to be of precisely the slide size width (height proportionally). And obviously i want to have it in the centre of a slide.

Comment: `\resizebox{11.5cm}{!}{` adds space to the left and is presumably not the width you want, try `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%`

Comment: it is better now but there are still margins i want this table to occupy the whole slide, with very small margins (almost without any).

Comment: Oh OK go back to a specific length then but add `\makebox[0pt]{\resizebox....}` around it then you can make it as wide as you like and it will just bleed off the end of the screen if you push it too far.

Answer (score 3):

Are two-line column headers acceptable to you?

[image]

I add `makecell` package for simple settings of column headers and `siunitx` for nicer numbers align in the third column:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{polski}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor,hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usetheme{boxes}
\usecolortheme{default}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\beamersetaveragebackground{white}
\pretocmd{\tableofcontents}{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}}{}{}
\apptocmd{\tableofcontents}{\end{minipage}}{}{}
  \usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{table}[]
        \centering
        \caption{My caption}
        \label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|S[table-format=2.0]|c|c|}
    \hline
\thead{Kraj} & \thead{Okres zwiększonej\\ podaży pieniądza} 
                & {\thead{Liczba\\ kwartałów}}      
                    & \thead{Liczba\\ epizodów}       
                        & \thead{Inflacja}                   \\ \hline
    Kanada                 & 1972 Q1 - 1974 Q2                  & 4                     & 5                     & {\color[HTML]{009901} TAK} \\ \hline
    & 1978 Q4 - 1983 Q1                  & 18                    &                       & {\color[HTML]{FE0000} NIE} \\ \hline
    & 1986 Q4 - 1987 Q3                  & 4                     &                       & {\color[HTML]{FE0000} NIE} \\ \hline
    & 1990 Q3 - 1993 Q4                  & 14                    &                       & {\color[HTML]{FE0000} NIE} \\ \hline
    & 1996 Q1 - 1998 Q4                  & 12                    &                       & {\color[HTML]{009901} TAK} \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}              & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}      \\ \hline
    Dania                  & 1975 Q4 - 1978 Q1                  & 10                    & 4                     & {\color[HTML]{009901} TAK} \\ \hline
    & 1984 Q2 - 1988 Q4                  & 19                    &                       & {\color[HTML]{FE0000} NIE} \\ \hline
    & 1992 Q2 - 1994 Q3                  & 10                    &                       & {\color[HTML]{009901} TAK} \\ \hline
    & 1996 Q4 - 1999 Q3                  & 12                    &                       & {\color[HTML]{009901} TAK} \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}              & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}      \\ \hline
    Francja                & 1990 Q3 - 1993 Q4                  & 14                    & 2                     & {\color[HTML]{FE0000} NIE} \\ \hline
    & 1995 Q3 - 1996 Q3                  & 4                     &                       & {\color[HTML]{FE0000} NIE} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
%}
\end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
See, if you like the following, more professional look of table. For it I use package `booktabs`. I also rearrange your preamble, than now is more consistent and delete repeating load of some package and also package loaded by `beamer` (\graphicx`,`hyperref`) and select small font size (`\small`).

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}
\usetheme{boxes}
\usecolortheme{default}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\beamersetaveragebackground{white}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,
                calc,
                intersections,
                shapes}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\usepackage{booktabs,makecell}% <-- added
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small}% <-- added
\usepackage{siunitx}% <-- added

\pretocmd{\tableofcontents}{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}}{}{}
\apptocmd{\tableofcontents}{\end{minipage}}{}{}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{table}
        \centering
    \caption{My caption}
        \label{my-label}
    \small
\begin{tabular}{ccS[table-format=2.0]cc}
    \toprule
\thead{Kraj} 
        &   \thead{Okres zwiększonej\\ podaży pieniądza} 
            &   {\thead{Liczba\\ kwartałów}}
                &   \thead{Liczba\\ epizodów}
                    &   \thead{Inflacja}                                \\
    \midrule
Kanada  & 1972 Q1 - 1974 Q2 &   4   &   5   & {\color[HTML]{009901} TAK} \\
        & 1978 Q4 - 1983 Q1 &  18   &       & {\color[HTML]{FE0000} NIE} \\
        & 1986 Q4 - 1987 Q3 &   4   &       & {\color[HTML]{FE0000} NIE} \\
        & 1990 Q3 - 1993 Q4 &  14   &       & {\color[HTML]{FE0000} NIE} \\
        & 1996 Q1 - 1998 Q4 &  12   &       & {\color[HTML]{009901} TAK} \\
    \midrule
Dania   & 1975 Q4 - 1978 Q1 &  10   &   4   & {\color[HTML]{009901} TAK} \\
        & 1984 Q2 - 1988 Q4 &  19   &       & {\color[HTML]{FE0000} NIE} \\
        & 1992 Q2 - 1994 Q3 &  10   &       & {\color[HTML]{009901} TAK} \\
        & 1996 Q4 - 1999 Q3 &  12   &       & {\color[HTML]{009901} TAK} \\
    \midrule
Francja & 1990 Q3 - 1993 Q4 &  14   &   2   & {\color[HTML]{FE0000} NIE} \\
        & 1995 Q3 - 1996 Q3 &   4   &       & {\color[HTML]{FE0000} NIE} \\ 
        \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based on [David Carlisles comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287611/table-to-fit-beamer-slide#comment695612_287611):

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor,hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usetheme{boxes}
\usecolortheme{default}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\beamersetaveragebackground{white}
\pretocmd{\tableofcontents}{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}}{}{}
\apptocmd{\tableofcontents}{\end{minipage}}{}{}
  \usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{table}[]
            \centering
            \caption{My caption}
            \label{my-label}
            \makebox[0pt]{\resizebox{.98\paperwidth}{!}{%
            \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
                \hline
                Kraj                   & Okres zwiększonej podaży pieniądza & Liczba kwartałów      & Liczba epizodów       & Inflacja                   \\ \hline
                Kanada                 & 1972 Q1 - 1974 Q2                  & 4                     & 5                     & {\color[HTML]{009901} TAK} \\ \hline
                & 1978 Q4 - 1983 Q1                  & 18                    &                       & {\color[HTML]{FE0000} NIE} \\ \hline
                & 1986 Q4 - 1987 Q3                  & 4                     &                       & {\color[HTML]{FE0000} NIE} \\ \hline
                & 1990 Q3 - 1993 Q4                  & 14                    &                       & {\color[HTML]{FE0000} NIE} \\ \hline
                & 1996 Q1 - 1998 Q4                  & 12                    &                       & {\color[HTML]{009901} TAK} \\ \hline
                \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}              & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}      \\ \hline
                Dania                  & 1975 Q4 - 1978 Q1                  & 10                    & 4                     & {\color[HTML]{009901} TAK} \\ \hline
                & 1984 Q2 - 1988 Q4                  & 19                    &                       & {\color[HTML]{FE0000} NIE} \\ \hline
                & 1992 Q2 - 1994 Q3                  & 10                    &                       & {\color[HTML]{009901} TAK} \\ \hline
                & 1996 Q4 - 1999 Q3                  & 12                    &                       & {\color[HTML]{009901} TAK} \\ \hline
                \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}              & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}      \\ \hline
                Francja                & 1990 Q3 - 1993 Q4                  & 14                    & 2                     & {\color[HTML]{FE0000} NIE} \\ \hline
                & 1995 Q3 - 1996 Q3                  & 4                     &                       & {\color[HTML]{FE0000} NIE} \\ \hline
            \end{tabular}}}
        \end{table}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `columns` environment with a unique column:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor,hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usetheme{boxes}
\usecolortheme{default}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\beamersetaveragebackground{white}
\pretocmd{\tableofcontents}{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}}{}{}
\apptocmd{\tableofcontents}{\end{minipage}}{}{}
  \usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

  \begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \caption{My caption}
    \label{my-label}
    \begin{columns}
      \column{\paperwidth}
      \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
          \hline
          Kraj                   & Okres zwiększonej podaży pieniądza & Liczba kwartałów      & Liczba epizodów       & Inflacja                   \\ \hline
          Kanada                 & 1972 Q1 - 1974 Q2                  & 4                     & 5                     & {\color[HTML]{009901} TAK} \\ \hline
                                 & 1978 Q4 - 1983 Q1                  & 18                    &                       & {\color[HTML]{FE0000} NIE} \\ \hline
                                 & 1986 Q4 - 1987 Q3                  & 4                     &                       & {\color[HTML]{FE0000} NIE} \\ \hline
                                 & 1990 Q3 - 1993 Q4                  & 14                    &                       & {\color[HTML]{FE0000} NIE} \\ \hline
                                 & 1996 Q1 - 1998 Q4                  & 12                    &                       & {\color[HTML]{009901} TAK} \\ \hline
          \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}              & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}      \\ \hline
          Dania                  & 1975 Q4 - 1978 Q1                  & 10                    & 4                     & {\color[HTML]{009901} TAK} \\ \hline
                                 & 1984 Q2 - 1988 Q4                  & 19                    &                       & {\color[HTML]{FE0000} NIE} \\ \hline
                                 & 1992 Q2 - 1994 Q3                  & 10                    &                       & {\color[HTML]{009901} TAK} \\ \hline
                                 & 1996 Q4 - 1999 Q3                  & 12                    &                       & {\color[HTML]{009901} TAK} \\ \hline
          \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}              & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}      \\ \hline
          Francja                & 1990 Q3 - 1993 Q4                  & 14                    & 2                     & {\color[HTML]{FE0000} NIE} \\ \hline
                                 & 1995 Q3 - 1996 Q3                  & 4                     &                       & {\color[HTML]{FE0000} NIE} \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}}
    \end{columns}
  \end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```